# Piranha CMS UI menu returns empty on post page

Tags: piranha-cms

I have the default template menu from the piranha install. It works very well for all the pages of the site, but when it comes to viewing individual post pages the menu bar is empty, even when I specifically define root node as the startpage of the site.

Why is this? Can I make UI.Menu output the same html as on the other pages of the site in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a root node, or start level for the menu, that page, or a child of the page has to be active in order for the menu to render. This is the logic that enables you to easily render submenus by typing:

```
@UI.Menu(StartLevel: 2)
```

When you render a post you don't have a selected position in the site map, so rendering the menu from a certain root node will most likely return empty. However, rendering the level without a root node should give you a menu, for example:

```
@UI.Menu(StopLevel: 2)
```

To help you out I need to know just how you're invoking the menu-helper from you .cshtml file.

Regards

Håkan